# why soak test is ended before the time i set in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

i set up a 16-hour soak test in jmeter. use a csv file for different users for 10000 users. use ultimate thread group with these settings:

one row

start threads count: 20

initial delay: 0

start up time : 60 sec

hold for load : 57600 sec

shut down time : 10

i run the test 3 times. all of them ended in 8-9 hours.

on the server pc, i look for some settings of iis but didnt see anything.

the second day, in view result tree there was a response such that:

sampler result page

response message: non http response message: en established comnection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

does jmeter any limitation or iis have some timeout value?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter doesn't have any internal "timeouts" for the test, it might be the case you test has.

For example I can think of 2 possible options:

1. Your [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) has either `Recycle on EOF` set to `True` or `Stop thread on EOF` set to `False` so when all 10000 lines are used the test stops
2. Your [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) is configured to `Stop Thread` or `Stop Test` on the error and your test terminates when error occurs

   [image]

The exact reason for stopping the test can be found in the [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

Comment: unfortunately not related for these two. the settings are correct